# How do a use a SecureString to create a SHA1 or SHA512 Hash?

Tags: .net, hash, sha1, sha512, securestring

I would like to use a SecureString varible within VB.NET and convert that to a SHA1 or SHA512 hash.  How would I securely convert the SecureString to the Byte array that HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash will accept?

Answer (score -1):

What about that, if we avoid the only used String instance (output) and replace it with a character array. This would enable us to wipe this array after use:

```
    public static String SecureStringToMD5( SecureString password )
    {
        int passwordLength = password.Length;
        char[] passwordChars = new char[passwordLength];

        // Copy the password from SecureString to our char array
        IntPtr passwortPointer = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR( password );
        Marshal.Copy( passwortPointer, passwordChars, 0, passwordLength );
        Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR( passwortPointer );

        // Hash the char array
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash( Encoding.Default.GetBytes( passwordChars ) );

        // Wipe the character array from memory
        for (int i = 0; i < passwordChars.Length; i++)
        {
            passwordChars[i] = '\0';
        }

        // Your implementation of representing the hash in a readable manner
        String hashString = ConvertToHexString( hashedPasswordBytes );

        // Return the result
        return hashString;
    }
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Yes - see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293344/hashing-a-securestring-in-net